# What is the definition of "language feature" in programming

Tags: ecmascript-6, programming-languages, language-features

I see that for such a widely used term I cannot find any definition or  dedicated wikipedia article. I also use the term but I'm not sure whether I use it correctly in all cases.

By looking at sites that describe language features (e.g. http://es6-features.org) I can have a sense of what they are, but without specific bounds.

I also see that features are usually categorized (like in the above site). But again I cannot find any site mentioning about categorization of programming language features.

Comment: Let's put it this way. This is a 'feature', **Object\`foo\` instanceof Array === true**. And this is a 'bug', **typeof null === 'object'**.

Answer (score 0):

The word *feature*  for programming languages is used with the meaning of *characteristic* or *attribute*, so there doesn't need to be a specific definition. See the word's definition through [Google](https://www.google.co.ve/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=feature+meaning&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=UbYVWaC3JNHI8AfS6J6ADQ).

> fea·ture
>
> noun: feature; plural noun: features
>
> 1. a distinctive attribute or aspect of something. "safety features like dual air bags" synonyms: characteristic, attribute, quality,
>      property, trait, hallmark, trademark;
>
>    - a part of the face, such as
>        the mouth or eyes, making a significant contribution to its overall
>        appearance. synonyms: face, countenance, physiognomy;
>    - LINGUISTICS
>        a distinctive characteristic of a linguistic unit, especially a speech
>        sound or vocabulary item, that serves to distinguish it from others of
>        the same type.

Comment: But shouldn't the definition at least include the types of features or some kind of grouping? I think distinctive attributes like:  Simple, Distributed, Object-Oriented, closures, duck-typing support, strongly-typed, Multiple inheritance, Generators, Currying, Compound types are too irrelevant to each other to be referenced by the same term. I think clustering them under more specific groups (terms), would provide a deeper understanding of what they actually are.